# ViewPager inside RecyclerView

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` with about 20 viewpagers (`viewpager` with fragment)
I want to display different pictures inside this viewpagers with the hel of fragments.
But I have some problems with this viewpagers. The first `viewpager` is ok!, but the next 19 is clear, without any pics. After scroll down and up, the pictures appears in `viewpager`, but after swipe on `viewpager` they disappear.

Here is the `viewpager` adapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
ArrayList<String> mPics;
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<String> pics) {
    super(fm);
    mPics = pics;
    for (String pic: mPics) {
        Log.d("!!!!!!!->",pic);
    }
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return ViewPagerFragment.newInstance(mPics,position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mPics.size();
}}
```

and recyclerview onBindViewHolder

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FlatViewHolder flatViewHolder, int position) {

    Flat flat = mFlat.get(position);

    if (flat.getAdv_pics().size()>0){

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( fragmentManager,(ArrayList) flat.getAdv_pics()  );
        flatViewHolder.viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    }else{

    }
}
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find solution to this problem ?

Comment: @SpeedDemon try to add an ID to every pager, like pager.setId(position+1);